# Hamiltonian system ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

I'm stuck in this exercise and I don't know how to proceed.

A system $$x'=f(x,y) \\ y'=g(x,y)$$

is a Hamiltonian if there is a function $H(x,y)$ such that $$f=H_y,\\ g=-H_x$$

The $H$ function is called Hamiltonian.

I need to prove that any conservative equation $x''=f(x)$ implies a Hamiltonian System, and I need to prove that the Hamiltonian function $H$ coincides to the total energy.

How I prove these two facts?

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, a Hamiltonian $H(x,y)$ for $x,y$ is a function such that
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\\
\end{align}
For the system $x''(t)=f(x)$ consider the function $y(t)=x'(t)$. It follows then that
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y(t)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= x''(t)=f(x)\\
\end{align}
Thus your Hamiltonian function $H(x,x')$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} &= -y\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} &= f(x)
\end{align}
Well the function
$H(x,y)= -\frac{y^2}{2} + \int_0^x f(t)dt$ satisfies the PDE constraints above. Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you mean $H=-\frac12y^2+F(x)$? This might suggest that the other sign convention, $\dot x=H_y$, $\dot y=-H_x$, leads to the more conventional energy function.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes good catch, you can switch the sign. Just need to make sure you are clear with which one you are satisfying

Comment: Usually it is $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(q)$ for the simple separable cases, so that with $p=m\dot q$ the impulse one has $\dot q = p/m=H_p$ and then $\dot p=-H_q=-V'(x)=f(x)$.